Film about a girl who discovers she is from a family of magicians
It's a live action movie, which I think has to be from the years 2008-2012.
In my memories the image was pretty good quality but you could tell it was a low budget movie.
For some reason I think it was French.
If I'm not mistaken a girl discovers that she comes from a family of wizards and goes to explore the magical part of the city, which is located underground.
In this place there are magical creatures and I think a magic school from where the girl's mother was expelled (I think, if my memory serves me correctly).

Sorry, but I saw the title and this is what popped in my head: "You're a wizard, Harriet"

"You're a magician, Harriet"

I'm pretty sure it's not what you're looking for, but it seems analogous to Sabrina the Teenage Witch.

I have found the film.
It's called Saxana: The Little Witch and the Enchanted Book.
It turns out it was Czech and not French. I remembered the plot pretty well, but until I see it again I won't confirm. I think the difference from what I said is that the mother is an important witch.

Don't forget to come back to accept your answer by clicking on the check mark by the voting buttons. As a self-answer, you won't be able to completely process until 48 hours from when you ask the question.

If it's the right one, you might be interested to know that it's a sequel of a 1971/72 movie "The Girl on the Broomstick" (about the mother's youth), which is generally regarded as the better of the two.

@AngewisnolongerproudofSO Oh I didn't know that, I would be interested in seeing it as well, although I was searching yesterday attempting to find the second one and nothing.

@Annie It's finadble under its Czech name (Dívka na koštěti), but whether any non-Czech subtitles (let alone dubbing) exist is another question.
